# Why when launching Xcode UITests takes too much time with Network Link Conditioner enabled?

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

When I run my UITests on my iPhone 6s with Network Link Conditioner enabled (very bad network setting and connected to my mac), Xcode takes too much time to **start** the tests.

I understand that the interaction within my app will be slower because of the link conditioner, but I don't understand why takes too much time when **starting/launching** the test, before even get to the splash screen. As far as I know there is no network call at this point.

Thanks in advance.